# Parsing iframe HTML code to get just the src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to be able to take Iframe HTML code like the following...

```
<iframe src="https://example.com" width="100" height="100"></iframe>
```

and from it just get the `src` attribute: https://example.com

I will need to get the `src` attribute in javascript.

I have tried doing the following:

```
var iframeCode = `<iframe src="https://example.com" width="100" height="100"></iframe>`
document.getElementById("tmpElement").outerHTML = iframeCode
var src = document.getElementById("tmpElement").childNodes[0].src
```

It works, but there is a security flaw with this approach. If the page I set in the iframe code contains javascript, it would *execute.* While this is normal behaviour, I need help to find a solution which will either not execute the javascript or get the src without loading the iframe (this may be possible with regex, possibly?, but I am no expert at regex.)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You could use DOMParser, which can turn an HTML string into a document without any possibility of executing unsafe code (like scripts or inline handlers):

```js
const str = '<iframe src="https://example.com" width="100" height="100"></iframe>';
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
console.log(doc.body.children[0].src);
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful, and has solved my problem. I will mark as answer in 7 minutes, when I can